# Check if condition is satisfied for each group in GROUP BY in BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a seemingly simple question. Hopefully it is not a dupe, I have been searching but I couldn't find anything specifically similar.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+------+----------+--------+--------+
|  id  | group_id | fruit  | color  |
|------+----------+--------+--------+
|   1  |    1     | apple  | red    |
|   2  |    1     | orange | orange |
|   3  |    1     | banana | yellow |
|   4  |    2     | kiwi   | golden |
|   5  |    2     | banana | yellow |
|   6  |    3     | orange | orange |
|   7  |    3     | peach  | orange |
|   8  |    3     | grape  | red    |
|   9  |    3     | apple  | green  |
|  10  |    3     | kiwi   | brown  |
+------+----------+--------+--------+
```

I would simply like to check if each group contains or not an `apple` fruit, resulting in a table like:

```
+----------+------------+
| group_id | has_apple  |
+----------+------------+
|    1     |    true    |
|    2     |    false   |
|    3     |    true    |
+----------+------------+
```

After <s>some</s> way too much time, the only way I managed to obtain that result is with this query:

```
SELECT group_id, 
       MAX(temp) AS has_apple 
FROM
    (SELECT group_id,
            MAX(IF(fruit='apple',true,false)) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) AS temp
     FROM t)
GROUP BY group_id
```

Okay, it works... and I hope it generalizes well enough to be put in my way more complex original query. My question is:

**Is there a better / slimmer / easier way to obtain the same result, maybe using only one `SELECT`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select group_id,
       (countif( fruit = 'apple') > 0) as apple_flag
from t
group by group_id
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I am going to wait some time, then I'll accept your answer!